# I can't start my apache

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I installed Xampp couple months ago. After i install it i've changed my port to 7777 and it runs smoothly without any problem. But couple days ago i download laravel into my computer and somehow i can't start my apache. It says port 80 is being used

```
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Player\vmware-hostd.exe" -u "C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml"" with PID 4252!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
10:57:29 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

i've changed the port on httpd.conf and i've tried to stop World Wide Web Publishing Service . Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you've installed VMware too,
goto Services and stop VMware's Services.
Restart XAMPP server.

other option is

1. start XAMPP
2. Click on Config and select Apache(httpd.conf)
3. Search for "Listen 80" and "ServerName localhost:80"
4. Change it to "Listen 8080" and "ServerName localhost:8080"
5. Restart the server and hit http://localhost:8080/